# Laravel MethodNotAllowed when using POST to /store resource

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I'm using Laravel 5.

I have an "orders" resource like so:

```
Route::resource('orders', 'OrdersController');
```

This creates the following routes:

```
|        | POST      | orders                            | orders.store      

    | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@store          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders                            | orders.index          | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@index          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders/create                     | orders.create         | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@create         | web          |
|        | DELETE    | orders/{order}                    | orders.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@destroy        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders/{order}                    | orders.show           | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@show           | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | orders/{order}                    | orders.update         | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@update         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders/{order}/edit               | orders.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@edit           | web          |
```

Thus, I am trying to use jQuery to POST to my order/store, like so:

```
function StoreOrder(name, supplier, quantity, catnum, notes, urgency){
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'text',
  url: 'orders/store',
  data: {
    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
    name: name,
    supplier: supplier,
    quantity: quantity,
    catnum: catnum,
    notes: notes,
    urgency: urgency
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    console.log('AJAX Error: ' + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
  },
  success:function(data){
    Materialize.toast(data);
    //Clear the form
  }
})


}
```

**But I am receiving a 'MethodNotAllowed' error.**

This is my first attempt at using AJAX with laravel. I'm very comfortable using AJAX in my own procedural code but now with Laravel I've run into some hiccups. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

EDIT: Realized I should probably show my controller code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Announcement;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use View;
use Auth;

class OrdersController extends Controller {

  public function index(){
   //show my page
}

  public function store(Order $order){
    //get a pleasing time stamp
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    //stores a post in the database
    $order->create([
      'name'      => Request::input('name'),
      'supplier'  => Request::input('supplier'),
      'quantity'  => Request::input('quantity'),
      'catnum'    => Request::input('catnum'),
      'notes'     => Request::input('notes'),
      'urgency'   => Request::input('urgency'),
      'author'    => Auth::user()->username,
      'date'      => $today,
      'status'    => 'Processing'
    ]);

    return ('Order created successfully.');

  }

}
```

Comment: The table says the route is `orders`, not `orders/store`.

Comment: ah ok, so as long as I'm sending a POST request to the /orders URI, it will use the store method from my OrdersController?

Comment: yes, just change `url: 'orders'`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! Now onto the next error :)
token mismatch error. I'll try to get this one myself.

Comment: @Vrans - the token mismatch is a common one you need to send the CSRF token as a header not part of the request.